# Where is SDL.dll located with compiling SDL 1.3 in mingw

Tags: c++, dll, mingw, sdl

I have compiled SDL 1.3 from source.
However I am having trouble finding sdl.dll - I see those files, but they are 3mb. I downloaded an example tutorial and the sdl.dll file included was 300kb (presumably 1.2)

When I attempt to compile and run my own programs they compile just fine...but they do absolutly nothing when run from ming or from explorer. - which I understand to be a dll problem. I have placed the dll that I found in the build directory

```
C:\Tools\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\*username*\SDL-1.3.0-5538\build\.libs
```

doing a search throughout the entire mingw directory shows one other version of SDL.dll that is 100kb smaller at 2.9mb....neither one of them work.

If I use the SDL.dll from 1.2 (included with the tutorial) programs run but have to be forced closed.

This also happens when building with codeblocks and with mingw. ---- ompiles fine...but cnat find valid version of sdl.dll

Answer (score 2):

It is probably easier if you build it through the VisualC folder located inside the SDL Folder. If all goes well you should be able to find it inside the Debug folder. It will be exactly 1.10 MB.

C:\SDL\VisualC\Debug

Hope this helps.